How to proof that G is a PRG?
I followed a lesson this year about Introduction to Cryptography and Anonymous Communication and I am going to retake the exam of this lesson.
I was doing exercises to practice but we don't have the solutions for the old exam questions so I need help to solve this.
Here is the question :
Question 1: Pseudorandom Generators
(a) Let $F:\{0,1\}^n \times \{0,1\}^n \rightarrow \{0,1\}^n$ be a public PRF (Pseudorandom Function).
Define $G_1(s)$ for any input of size $n$ as follows:

$t_1 = F(c, s)$
$t_2 = F(t_1, s)$
$G_1(s) = (t_1 \oplus t_2)$

where $c$ is a public constant defined on $\{0,1\}^n$ (the adversary knows $F(c,.)$ ), and $\oplus$ denotes the bitwise XOR operation. Is $G_1$ a PRG (Pseudorandom Generator)? Justify your answer.
Hint: Make sure to read the definition of a PRG carefully.

I don't know how to prove that $G_1$ is a PRG or not.
We also have the same exercise but with $G_2(s)$ as follows :

$t_1 = F(c, s)$
$t_2 = F(c, t_1)$
$G_2(s) = (t_1, t_2)$

And we have to prove that $G_2$ is not a PRG, so we are sure that this is not a PRG and my mind tells me that is because of the dependence between $t_1$ and $t_2$. But I have no proof...
Can anyone tell me how to solve the first question and what is the answer (yes or no)?
Thank you for your attention!

Are you interpreting the first argument of F as the seed or the second argument? Because if the first argument of F is the seed, then neither of these is (necessarily) a secure PRG.

Have you read the definition carefully, as suggested?

Thank you for your answer !
The first argument of the F function (PRF) is a constant that represents the key, et the variable s is the input that we put into the PRF so that we can take the key to cipher the input. So we use c to cipher s. But here, the s is also the seed of the PRG.
But I don't know how this is enough to tell that G1 is not a PRG.

And yes we try to respond with the definition but we are not sure about our answer...
In my opinion, G1 is not a PRG because we know the constant "c" and the adversary can compute F(c,.), so he can make t1 identifiable. Then if we have information about t1, we can find the way to have information about t2 because t2 is dependent of t1.
Then, we know about t1 and t2, so G1 can not be a PRG because a PRG has to be indistinguishable. We can not guess a bit in the sequence. But I am not sure about the explaination...

Hint for G1: there are two conditions for a PRG. You're focusing on the wrong one.

The question is NOT stating the complete definition of a PRG!

The security game of a PRF states that you can't tell the difference between a

Privately sample a key $k\gets \{0,1\}^n$.
On input $x_1,...,x_t$, output $F(k,x_1),...,F(k,x_t)$

vs

On input $x_1,...,x_t$, output random values $y_1,...,y_t$

Can you construct such an $F$ such that for your construction the whole thing is broken. For example, I could give you an $F$ such that the result of your $G$ is any value I want, e.g. 0.
Your task is to some up with a counter example, which in this case means make a good PRF that when used above is broken. Hint, start with a good PRF $F'$ and create a new $F$ that is broken when used as above.

Thank you for your answer, but we try to find a counter example.
The problem is that the question does not explain what the function F is doing. We just know that F is a function (PRF) that takes a pair of two elements in {0,1} and return an element in {0,1}. So we don't know how to find a good counter example...
To find a counter example, we would have to know how to use the F function, but it is not there.

ok, I'll give you another hint. Here is my code for a strong PRF $F'$.
$$$
F'(k,x) = AES.Enc(k,x)
$$
So depending on how strong you think AES is, you can actually prove that $G$ implemented with $F'$ is a PRG. But thats proof might be too advanced. Moreover, thats not what we want. You want to show that $G$ isn't a PRG for some  PRF $F$. Your task is to take $F'$, modify it in some way to get $F$ such that $G$ is broken.
An example,
$$
F(k,x) = if\ x=k, return 0; otherwise\ return\ F'(k,x)
$$

this $F$ might not break $G$ but it can be inspiration. Additionally, you have to show that if $F'$ is a strong PRF (you can just assume it), then $F$ is also a strong PRF.

in summary, you need to

construct a $F$ and prove that its meets the PRF definition. You can assume the existence of some other PRF $F'$ as a building block.
show that $G$ does not implement a PRG. Give an attacker that can tell if the output is from $G$ or is actually just random.

